# combine multiple dictionaries of pandas dataframes by dictionary key and common columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dictionary

I have four dictionaries created by splitting four data frames by group I now need to join the data frames from each dictionary into a new dictionary using  the key and common columns as join conditions.

for example:

```
import pandas as pd
from functools import reduce


df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'Group': ['A','B','C'] , 'ID': [1,2,3],'count': [10, 20, 30], 'colors': ['red', 'white', 'blue']})

df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'Group': ['A','B','C'] , 'ID': [1,2,3],'time': [1.3, 2.5, 3]})

df_3 = pd.DataFrame({'Group': ['A','B','C'] , 'ID': [1,2,3],'order_num': [2, 4, 7]})

df_4 = pd.DataFrame({'Group': ['A','B','C'] , 'ID': [1,2,3],'result': ['g','b','b']})

dict1= dict(tuple(df_1.groupby('Group')))
dict2= dict(tuple(df_2.groupby('Group')))
dict3= dict(tuple(df_3.groupby('Group')))
dict4= dict(tuple(df_4.groupby('Group')))
```

Desired results using manual solution:

```
datA=[dict1['A'],dict2['A'],dict3['A'],dict4['A']]
datB=[dict1['B'],dict2['B'],dict3['B'],dict4['B']]
datC=[dict1['C'],dict2['C'],dict3['C'],dict4['C']]

final_dict = {'A' : reduce(lambda left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on=['Group','ID']), datA),
            'B' : reduce(lambda left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on=['Group','ID']), datB),
            'C' : reduce(lambda left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on=['Group','ID']), datC)}
```

Any help with finding a scalable non-manual solution would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this dynamic enough?

```
# Put all your dicts into a dict of dicts
dict_dict = {str(i):dict_i for i,dict_i in enumerate([dict1,dict2,dict3,dict4])}

# swap the order of the indices so groups are keys and the
# list of grouped dfs are the items
dat_dicts = {group_key:[df_dict[group_key] for df_dict in dict_dict.values()]
             for group_key in list(dict_dict.values())[0].keys()}

# Apply the reduce on each group key to merge the dfs
merged_dat_df_dict = {group_key:reduce(lambda left,right:
                                 pd.merge(left,right,on=['Group','ID']),
                                 dat_df_list)
                      for group_key,dat_df_list in dat_dicts.items()}
```

Comment: nice solution! I'm new to python could you explain in words the `dat_dicts` code block. In particular the `for group_key in list(dict_dict.values())[0].keys()` section.  Why the zeroth index?

Comment: The whole line is a list comprehension within a dictionary comprehension. The for statement you ask about gets each of the keys from the first sub-dict (dict1) of `dict_dict`. The call `list(dict_dict.values())` makes a list of your initial dicts (`dict1`,...,`dict4`). Since each of those dicts have the same keys (A, B, C) I just arbitrarily get keys from the first one (index 0). I then use those keys to get the item in each of your initial dicts (`for df_dict in dict_dict.values()`)